# Need to have repositories list for flash application testing using selenium-webdriver

Tags: maven, flash, selenium-webdriver

Jars required to test flash application along with selenium indicated below. Appreciate your help.

flash-selenium.jar
flashselenium-java-client-extension.jar
flex-ui-selenium-0.1.1.jar

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for here.

Comment: At present i am testing flash application using selenium-web-driver and it's non-maven project. We are planning to migrate to maven in order to achieve that i am looking for maven repositories (dependencies). I am configuring the the following flash dependent jars on non-maven project. flash-selenium.jar,flashselenium-java-client-extension.jar,flex-ui-selenium-0.1.1.jar. Appreciate your help!!